# Is the free product $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ linear over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Let $H:=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\langle p,q| q^n=1\rangle.$ I want to know if $H$ is a ($\mathbb{Z}$)linear group that is to say is there an injective homomorphism $f: H\to GL_m(\mathbb{Z})$ for $m\geq n.$
I asked the question on Math Stack Exchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430677/is-the-free-product-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-a-linear-group) and Derek Holt suggested me to also ask it here.
By advance thank you.

Comment: Can't you use that it has a free subgroup of finite index?  This subgroup has a faithful Z-linear representation and you can induce it to the whole group. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes that sounds good! The normal closure of $\langle p \rangle$  is a free subgroup of rank $n$ and of index $n$ in $H$. Since ${\rm GL}_2({\mathbb Z})$ contains free subgroups, we get a faithful representation of $H$ of degree $2n$. I should have thought of that myself - but I was trying to find a representation of degree $n$.

Comment: I might as well make this an answer.

Comment: where can I find a detailed proof of the fact that a free group has a faithful representation over $\mathbb{Z}$ of degree $2?$

Comment: I have never heard of Kurosh theorem before. I read an article on Wikipedia and according to it, we have that normal closure of p say $N:=\langle q^kpq^{−k}|k∈{0,…,n−1}\rangle$ is the a product $F(X)*(*_{i\in I}A_i)*(*_{j\in J}B_j)$ where $X$ is a subset of $H$, $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(B_j)_{j\in I}$ are respectively families of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ But I don't see why we can get rid of the last two components to say $N$ is free and I don't see why $N$ has index n

Comment: Is the induction of a faithful representation over $\mathbb{Z}$ always faithful?

Comment: It's ok for the index of $N.$ My bad

Comment: Induction of a faithful representation is always faithful.

Comment: In a free product any element of finite order is conjugate to an element of a free factor. So the kernel of the projection to Z/N has no element of finite order so is free.

Comment: Also, it's not very hard to show directly (without using the Kurosh theorem) that $N$ is free on $p,p^q,p^{q^2},\ldots,p^{q^{n-1}}$.

Comment: I tried to prove this statement but I am stucked.
I set for $k\in\{0,\dots,n-1\},p_k=q^kpq^{-k}=q^kpq^{n-k}.$ To prove that $N$ is free on $p,p^q,p^{q^2},\ldots,p^{q^{n-1}},$ is it sufficient to prove that any word $p_0^{k_0}\cdots p_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}$ where $k_0,\dots,k_{n-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be written in words in $p,p^q,p^{q^2},\ldots,p^{q^{n-1}}?$

Comment: If I consider a word $p_0^{k_0}\cdots p_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}$ of $N,$ with $k_0,\dots,k_{n-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ I could rewrite it $p_0^{l_0}\cdots p_{n-1}^{l_{n-1}}$ with $l_0,\dots,l_{n-1}\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}.$ 
I can simplify it as $q^jp^{l_j}qp^{l_{j+1}}q\cdots p^{l_{n-1}}q.$ where $j$ is the smallest non negative integer such that $p_j=q^jp^{l_j}q^{-j}\neq0.$ I don't see how it is possible to write this word in terms of $p,p^q,p^{q^2},\ldots,p^{q^{n-1}}.$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The group $Z*Z/n$ is virtually free: the kernel $K$ of the projection to $Z/n$ is free of index $n$ (say by the Kurosh theorem and since each finite order element is conjugate to an element of $Z/n$). Since a free group has a faithful representation over $Z$ of degree 2, the induced representation of this representation gives a faithful representation over $Z$ of your group of degree $2n$.